# Timecircle issue with Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

@Wim Barelds

Dear Wim,

Can you help me out. I am using your plugin for a Facebook tab, but Facebook is giving a permission error at *line 154* which is:

```
if (window !== window.top && typeof window.top.TC_Instance_List !== "undefined") {
    TC_Instance_List = window.top.TC_Instance_List;
}
else {
    window.top.TC_Instance_List = TC_Instance_List;
}
```

Don't know what to do now, need it real bad.

Comment: Duplicate of your own question, [Countdown script inside facebook tab not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377266/countdown-script-inside-facebook-tab-not-working)

Comment: Yeah, but since he is the creator of that plugin, and how do i tag him. YOu can delete that question, since i wrote the code now.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have had a better chance of reaching me personally on github ;)

Anyway, you *can* remove the code you copy-pasted without any ill effects. Normally it helps when you're using (i)frames and are trying to do cross-frame stuff.